# How would a 1-nearest neighbour classifier based on the Euclidean distance classify the observation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, knn

What would be an answer to this?

Consider a dataset  **D**  that contains only two observations  1=(1,1)  and  2=(−1,−1) . Suppose that the class of the first observation is  1=0  and that the class of the second observation is  2=1 . How would a 1-nearest neighbour classifier based on the Euclidean distance classify the observation  =(2,3) ? What are the distances between this new observation and each observation in the dataset? [0.5 marks out of 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `x` is closer to `x_1` than to `x_2` (I'll let you compute the distances yourself), the classifier would assign the class of `x_1` to `x`, i.e. `0`